# Angular2 generator function

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular2 app, I would like to iterate over all days between `startDate` and `endDate`in a template. Something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let date of dateRange(startDate,endDate)">
    {{date}}
</div>
```

I realize that I could precalculate all these dates and store them in an array before displaying them, but I would rather not take up the memory. I have been reading up on javascript [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and it seems like in vanilla javascript, I could do this:

```
function* dateRange(start,end) { 
    let cur = start;
    while (cur <= end) {
        yield cur;
        cur.setDate(cur.getDate() + 1);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to use a generator function like this from within an Angular2 component which could be used in a template iterator?

Answer (score 1):

> that I could precalculate all these dates and store them in an array before displaying them, but I would rather not take up the memory

Any memory will be much much less than the memory used by the DOM with all those dom elements.

The only solution I can think of is making an array out of the generator before using `ngFor` and at that point why no just only use an array.