# Support for Iterables inside Angular 6+ Templates

Tags: angular, iterable

Question is, can we use Iterables (beside Arrays) for binding inside Angular 6+ html template? Or If we can then how is the correct way to do something like the pseudo code bellow?

Generally I made experiment with the code bellow and it renders on screen the keys but I get an error:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngForOf: [object Object]'. Current value: 'ngForOf: [object Object]'.

Here is a pseudo code example:

**MyComponent.ts**

```
public items = { itemA: {}, itemB: {} }
*getKeyNames(obj):ItterableIterator<string>
{
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for(let key of keys)
    {
       yield key;
     }
}
```

**MyComponent.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let key of getKeyNames(items)">
    <p>Key {{key}}</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: This error happens due to the angular lifecycle.. Here's a good read on [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Comment: @iLuvLogix Tnx this is clear but as you can see I am just iterating an object which is not changing. The problem is related to how Angular interprets generator functions but I am far from been an expert.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951555/angular2-generator-function